# Setting up git on Lamp server pushing from Windows 7 - SSH with PuTTY

Tags: git, ssh, lamp

Trying to set up a git environment but hitting a wall with finding instructional material...

I have git installed and working beautifully on windows locally, and separately on my LAMP server. They both have repositories, I can add, commit etc.

How do I make the two git servers talk? I can only find tutorials about connecting with github, but that doesn't help me.

I have Msysgit installed on windows and would like to use PuTTY. They each have ssh keys. Just not sure how to make them speak to each other...

Please advise... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to get two 'git servers' to 'talk to each other' is to add one repository as a remote to the other and then push to (and pull from) the remote ('remote' is git terminology). This would look something like this:

```
cd /path/to/repo
git remote add computer_b ssh://user@computer_b:path/to/repo.git
git pull computer_b
```

(all done on computer_a)

Comment: Thank you! All the tutorials I've found on setting up git get to one point and then start talking about github.

Comment: Do you know if I need git-daemon to do this?

Comment: No, you don't. The daemon provides more efficient communication channel, but using ssh (as in my example) is often sufficient (to get familiar with git at least). More info about the git protocols can be found here: http://progit.org/book/ch4-1.html (I recommend reading the whole book)

Comment: Thanks, will do! Do you know of a tutorial that would talk about how to set up the SSH on the server side? I created keys, just not sure about what to do with them...